# Git remote sent me a cryptic response

Tags: git, bitbucket

Terminal output:

```
git push --progress "origin" master

Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 2.26 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCC1''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''tCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCC,                                          ;GCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCi                                          tCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCf                                         .LCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCC,                                        :CCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCi                                        tCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCf                                       .LCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCC.           .LCCCCCCCCCCCCfi11111111111tCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCC;            1CCCCCCCCCCCC1iiii11111111LCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCt            :CCCCCCCCCCCCiiiiiii11111tCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCC.            LCCCCCCCCCCf;;;;iiiii111tCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCC;            iGCCCCCCCCCi;;;;;;iiiiiifCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCt            ,CCCCCCCCCC::::;;;;;;iiiLCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCC.            tLLLCCCCCt,:::::;;;;;;1CCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCC:              .....,,,,,,::::::;;;tCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCC1                ......,,,,,::::::;LCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCL                   .....,,,,,,:::;CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC:                    ......,,,,,:1CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC1                       .....,,,,fCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCL                         .....,:CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCL:::::::::::::::::::::::::;;;;iLCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote: CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
remote:
```

What the hell just happened? Should I be concerned about any security risks? I'm using bitbucket with git version 2.10.0.windows.1.

Color One:

[image]

Comment: Wait... is this a bitbucket logo in ASCII art?

Comment: Looks like an ascii art of bitbucket's logo

Comment: If your terminal would show colors, the message would have been clearer.

Comment: Facing the same.

Comment: First time facing this on bitbucket? what's wrong with bitbucket?????

Comment: I saw this today for the first time. Saw the colors.